# How to pass through the AntiForgeryToken in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to pass through the AntiForgeryToken to another action? The following does of course not work:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CheckSelection(string[] SelectedIds, int SessionId)
{
    ...
    if (SomeCondition)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Finish", "Session", new { SessionId = SessionId,
              __RequestVerificationToken = Request.Params["__RequestVerificationToken"] });
    }
    ....
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the scenario? Why do you need to pass it to another action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not possible. The anti-forgery token is based on both an Http Cookie and a hidden value in your Form; when doing an Action Redirect, that form value is lost and therefore the anti-forgery token cannot be validated.

You will need to come up with a design that does not need action redirect...

Comment: Thanks, we will do some reengineering here.

Comment: How did you end up doing this?