# MVC Redirects and AntiForgeryTokens

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two Post Actions :

**GetId**

**UpdateId**

The **GetId** action receives a number as argument (text input by the end user) that might be a new number or an existing one. If that number match the respective record on the database then it's a regular display data, if not an update must be made (I redirect to UpdateId action).

The **UpdateId** action also work as a independent worker for record updates and in the end it redirects to **GetId**.

So I basically have two actions that redirect between each other.

Now I tried to implement the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` and guess what, it doesn't work when the redirect happens since the redirect to action is a Get Method.

What should be the correct approach here? Passing the AntiForgeryToken on every redirect (assuming that's possible), or should I change the way my Controller actions work?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to redirect preserving the verb? `HTTP_STATUS_REDIRECT_KEEP_VERB`, status code `307`.  This way browser should resubmit the request to new URL using the same VERB as before.

Comment: @LB2 not sure how to do that. Can you please give an example?

Comment: I don't have good environment handy to validate code, so this is only rough outline.  When producing `HttpResponseMessage` in your MVC method, set response code to 307, and Location to the route for your redirect target route.  This should instruct browser to resubmit request in the same manner to the new location.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424331/how-to-pass-through-the-antiforgerytoken-in-mvc Thanks anyway