# How to pass an AntiForgeryToken from one controller action to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, antiforgerytoken

I have a form like this:

```
    using (Html.BeginForm("MockEcaCertLogin", "Authentication", new { area = "Login" }, FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="well">
            <h1 class="bg-danger" style="padding:3px; border: 1px solid black">Mock ECA Login</h1>
            <div class="margin-bottom-20 margin-top-20">

                @Html.DropDownList("CertName", new List<SelectListItem>()
            {
                new SelectListItem() { Text = "First Last", Value = "First .Last.M.CCCDDDDDDDDDD.ID" },
                new SelectListItem() { Text = "First Last", Value = "First Last" },
            })

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

This form posts to a controller action that looks like this:

```
        [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken, ValidateModelState]
        public void MockEcaCertLogin(string certName)
        {
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(this.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext);
            var destinationUrl = urlHelper.Action("Login", "Authentication");

            var headers = new NameValueCollection();
            headers.Add("X-ARR-ClientCert", certName);
            HttpContext.Server.TransferRequest(destinationUrl, true, "POST", headers);
        }
```

So the form posts a ValidateAntiForgery token to the Controller action.
And the action does a Transfer request to this action:

```
    //[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken, ValidateModelState]
    [HttpPost, ValidateModelState]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        var certificateName = GetCertificate();
```

How can I pass an AntiForgeryToken from the first action to the next one or create a new one to pass?

Usually we have a form posting to the second action so we gave the normal:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

line in the form.

But I am doing something from another form where I pass to the first action and then pass control to the second action.

But the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attrubute breaks it when I go this route.

Answer (score 1):

**That is not possible**. The anti-forgery token is based on both an Http Cookie and a hidden value in your Form; when doing an Action Redirect, that form value is lost and therefore the anti-forgery token cannot be validated.

You will need to come up with a design that does not need action redirect...

Credit:-Roy Dictus

[How to pass through the AntiForgeryToken to another action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424331/how-to-pass-through-the-antiforgerytoken-in-mvc)